# How do I delete lines less than N pixels long in an image?

Tags: java, image-processing

I have a gray scale Buffered Image of a retinal photograph. After processing with the Sobel and Canny algorithms I am left with several short lines around the image. These smaller lines are affecting an algorithm I have created to calculate the vessel width. I am trying to write an algorithm or identify one that can be used to delete all lines that are shorter than N pixels in length. This should clean the image as well as making my algorithm more effective.
Is there any algorithms out there for this type of problem? If not could anyone suggest where to start? I created the following to track a single line but it needs alot of work:

```
public static IntImage cleanImage(IntImage imageIn) {
    int width = imageIn.nCols, height = imageIn.nRows;
    IntImage image = new IntImage(height, width);
    image.setPixels(imageIn.getPixels().clone());
    int currentX = 0, currentY = 0, currentValue = 0, count = 0, counter = 0;
    int[][] locations = new int[50][2];
    boolean connectionFound = false;

    for(int row = 0; row < height-1; row++){
        for(int col = 1; col < width-1; col++){
            currentX=col;
            currentY=row;
            do{
                if(image.getPixel(currentY, currentX)==255){
                    locations[count][0]=currentY;
                    locations[count][1]=currentX;
                    ++count;
                }else if(image.getPixel(currentY, currentX+1)==255){
                    locations[count][0]=currentY;
                    locations[count][1]=currentX+1;
                    ++count;
                    currentX+=1;
                }else if(image.getPixel(currentY+1, currentX+1)==255){
                    locations[count][0]=currentY+1;
                    locations[count][1]=currentX+1;
                    ++count;
                    currentY+=1;
                    currentX+=1;
                }else if(image.getPixel(currentY+1, currentX)==255){
                    locations[count][0]=currentY+1;
                    locations[count][1]=currentX;
                    ++count;
                    currentY+=1;
                }else if(image.getPixel(currentY+1, currentX-1)==255){
                        locations[count][0]=currentY+1;
                        locations[count][1]=currentX-1;
                        ++count;
                        currentY+=1;
                        currentX-=1;
                }else if(image.getPixel(currentY, currentX-1)==255){
                    locations[count][0]=currentY;
                    locations[count][1]=currentX-1;
                    ++count;
                    currentX-=1;
                }
            }while(image.getPixel(currentY, currentX)==255 && count < 50);
            if(count < 50){
                for(int loop = 0; loop < 50; loop++){
                    image.setPixel(locations[loop][0], locations[loop][1], 0);
                    locations[loop][0]=0;
                    locations[loop][1]=0;
                }
            }
            count = 0;
            currentX = col;
            currentY = row;
        }
    }
    return image;
```

The code above is to show I am trying myself but please don't bother too much with it like I said it needs alot of work.
The Sobel and Canny algorithms are used to get the outlines of the vessels and then turn the image into a binary image. Its at that point that all the other lines can be seen. I cant process the image before this point. If I just use Canny without sobel its not as bad but the lines seem to be much wider and therefore inaccurate this way. Thats why I want to remove the smaller lines to make sure the area inside the vessel edges are clear for processing. Unfortunately I cant upload a picture because my reputation needs to be at least ten. Sorry.

Comment: Couldn't you process a **copy** of the retinal image with the Sobel and Canny algorithms?  That way, you wouldn't have to worry about removing anything.

Comment: That's actually what I am doing. I create a copy which is basically a 2D array of the data. I then process it with the Sobel and Canny algorithms. The problem is that the Canny algorithm after using Sobel leaves all these smaller lines. I've tried different thresholds for the Canny algorithm to reduce these but there is still plenty of them there.

Comment: I guess I still don't understand.  You make a copy of the data, you use the Sobel and Canny algorithms, you throw away the data with the results of the algorithm, and you do further processing on **another copy** of the data with no lines.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not quite sure if I understand. The Sobel and Canny algorithms are used to get the outlines of the vessels and then turn the image into a binary image. Its at that point that all the other lines can be seen. I cant process the image before this point. If I just use Canny without sobel its not as bad but the lines seem to be much wider and therefore inaccurate this way. Thats why I want to remove the smaller lines to make sure the area inside the vessel edges are clear for processing. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Ok, now I understand the problem.  I suggest adding your comment to the question, as well as a small section of the processed BufferedImage so we can see what the small lines that you're talking about look like.

Comment: Gilbert thanks for the tips. If you want to see a section of the image checkout my facebook page I live in Northern Ireland County L'Derry. My profile picture is myself with my son in his uniform.